# Running C++ DLL in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, c++, customize-mode

I've migrated a VB script that uses ArcObjects to a C++ Win32 DLL (using Visual Studio 2013).

Now I would like to test my DLL by launching it from my ArcMap 10.3 installation.

The problem is that when I try to add it through "Customize -> Customize Mode -> Add from file" it does not succeed and raises the following message: "Can't load type library from specified file", even when I run ArcMap as Administrator.
The same way, the "ESRIRegAsm.exe" I tried to use in command line also refuses to register my DLL.

I've made research but I could not find any answer to make it work.
But maybe I am not doing this the right way.

Do I need to implement a COM component to add my DLL to ArcMap?